# After change the password login is not working using Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I created the client register and the password change function. When I register the client with the password that password and username are working without any issues. But when I change the password and log in with a new password always says the password is incorrect.I can't understand what is the issue please help me to solve this issue.

**This is my register code**

```
public function store(Request $request, client $client)
    {
        
        $token = $request->input('g-recaptcha-response');

        if(strlen($token)>0)
        {
        
            $result = client::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    
            if (!empty($result))
            {
                return Redirect::back()->with('errmessage','The registered email address is already in use. Please contact the website administrator or request a password reset');
            }
    
            $client->clie_id = $request->email;
            $client->clie_fname = $request->clie_fname;
            $client->clie_lname = $request->clie_lname;
            $client->clie_company = $request->clie_company;
            $client->password = Hash::make($request->password);
            $client->email = $request->email;
            $client->clie_telephone = $request->clie_telephone;
            $client->clie_fax = $request->clie_fax;
            $client->clie_address1 = $request->clie_address1;
            $client->clie_address2 = $request->clie_address2;
            $client->clie_address3 = $request->clie_address3;
    
            $client->clie_city = $request->clie_city;
            $client->clie_state = $request->clie_state;
            $client->clie_postcode = $request->clie_postcode;
            $client->clie_country = $request->clie_country;
    
            $client->clie_newslatter= $request->clie_newslatter;
    
            $client->save();
    
            return Redirect::back()->with('message','Account Created Successfully. You may now login using the email you registered with and your password');
            
        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->with('warmessage','Please make sure your not a robot');
        }
    }
```

**This is my password change function**

```
public function PasswordChange(Request $request)
    {
        
        //dd($request->clientId);
        
        $token = $request->input('g-recaptcha-response');

        if(strlen($token)>0)
        {
            $user = Client::where('email', $request->clientId)->first();

            if (!$user) {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'User not found.');
            }
            
            if (!Hash::check($request->old_password, $user->password)) {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'The old password is incorrect.');
            }
            
            $user->update([
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
            ]);
            
            // Clear the user's session to ensure the new password takes effect
            Auth::guard('client')->logout();
        
            return redirect()->route('Home')->with('message','Password is Successfully changed.');
            
        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->with('message','Please make sure your not a robot');
        }

        // return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Password changed successfully.');
    }
```

**My login function**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        
        //dd($request->password);
        
        // Retrieve the user record by email
        $user = client::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        
        Log::info('Login attempt:', [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'entered_org_password' => $request->password,
            'entered_password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'hashed_password' => $user->password,
        ]);
        

        if(Auth::guard('client')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password],$request->remember))
        {
          return redirect('/')->withMessage('Successfully Logged In');
        }else{
            return redirect(route('Client_Login'))->with('Error');
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email'));
    }
```

**This is my Modal**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class client extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'client';

    protected $table='clients';

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
    
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**This is my log data when login with a new password**

After Registering this the records for login.

```
[2023-10-05 08:34:06] local.INFO: Login attempt: {"email":"james@gmail.com","entered_org_password":"123456789","entered_password":"$2y$10$1mR2dKLEJAHvv0BCQoCfZeLP5Ugq4ngTvHD4/RFDtXp.asB7AJKF.","hashed_password":"$2y$10$Jxm/cd25Xpe4i8ljfDV98uIICszGb61pV6PtcwuhqHayjujWsOejm"}
```

After changing the password and login records

```
[2023-10-05 08:35:21] local.INFO: Login attempt: {"email":"james@gmail.com","entered_org_password":"123456789123","entered_password":"$2y$10$49D4RS5aNWwl8xtnWOGeQ.wuT2Ozipz4O1yAtmJQAsmjoZiLQb3b.","hashed_password":"$2y$10$.dj8Egmzr0JDs7IlmMfZ2ultD5Srp5YTo0Wxi0WHmxscc0P1cpS3u"}
```

My password change form inputs

```
<form action="{{route('PasswordChange')}}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="form-fields">
            <div class="inputs">
              <label for="Email">Old Password</label>
              <input class="email" placeholder="Old Password" id="old_password" name="old_password" type="password"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="clientId" id="clientId" value="{{$clients->email}}">
            </div>
                
        <div class="inputs">
             <label for="Email">New Password</label>
                 <input class="email" placeholder="New Password" id="new_password" name="new_password" type="password"/>
        </div>
                
           <div class="inputs">
                <label for="Email">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input class="email" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password"/>
            </div>
                                                    
                                                  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="buttons">
                                                <input class="button-1 login-button" type="submit" value="Update" style="width: 25%;"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

And this my login page inputs

```
<form action="{{route('Client_Login.submit')}}" method="post">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-fields">
                                    <div class="message-error">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inputs">
                                        <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                                        <input  id="email" name="email" type="text"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inputs">
                                        <label for="Password">Password:</label>
                                        <input class="password" id="password" name="password" type="password" />
                                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inputs reversed">
                                        <label for="RememberMe">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ?'checked' : 'checked'}}> Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                        <span class="forgot-password">
                                            <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="forgot-password">
                                            |
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="forgot-password">
                                            <a href="{{route('FrontClient.index')}}">Register</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <input class="button-1 login-button" type="submit" value="Log in" />
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: is `password` fillable on the model?

Comment: Yes it's fillable

Comment: can you check to see if your form inputs for the update form are passing the values you expect?

Comment: where is the input named `password`?

Comment: Thanks that is the issue I didn't notice new_password is the input name

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using Laravel 5 or latest version but it's possible that password is double-hashed.

In latest Laravel version there is:

```
protected $casts = [
   'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
   'password' => 'hashed',
];
```

but assuming you are not using it you might have `setPasswordAttribute` in `User` model that hashes passwords.

So in your `PasswordChange` method you might need to change

```
$user->update([
   'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
]);
```

into

```
$user->update([
   'password' => $request->password
]);
```

Comment: it doesn't make a sense !

Answer (score -1):

Your update code is looking for an input named `password`. Your form has inputs named `old_password`, `new_password` and `confirm_password`. You are hashing `null`:

```
$user->update([
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
]);
```

I would suggest using the inputs named `old_password`, `password`, `password_confirmation` and to use validation. The `confirmed` validation rule exists and would be expecting `password_confirmation` for the name of the confirmation input for a field named `password`.